# BotMan - ответить картинкой в Conversation

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

Всем привет. Опять не гуглится один момент и в самой документации BotMan этого нет. Я создал несколько Conversations, где человека спрашивают "Вам показывать предложения?", он отвечает да/нет и в таком случаи либо получает список товаров, либо нет. Идея была в том, чтобы пользователь получал товар с картинкой (в методе reply это возможно, но тут есть ->say, который не выводит картинку). Соотвественно картинку я буду получать с сервера, прикреплять к сообщению и писать текст.

Может есть какие-то идеи или опыт такого кейса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Я просто взял и из контроллера передал BotMan класс в конструктор своего Conversation, так как в метод всегда приходит BotMan. Всё оказалось проще, хоть и само решение звучит сомнительно, а также нарушает Low Coupling. Но с точки зрения задачи - это, наверное, единственный способ добиться такого результата без костылей.